# Why would I be getting an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException from SAP HANA JDBC Driver?

Tags: java, jdbc, hana

I am configuring my connection pool as follows:

```
dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sap://********:30015");
dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver");
dataSource.setMaxActive(20);
dataSource.setMaxIdle(0);
dataSource.setMaxIdle(0);
dataSource.setUsername("*******");
dataSource.setPassword("*******");
```

However, when the connection gets initialized, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
        at com.sap.db.util.StructuredBytes.putBigUnicode(StructuredBytes.java:568)
        at com.sap.db.util.MemIndirection.putBigUnicode(MemIndirection.java:186)
        at com.sap.db.jdbc.packet.DataPartAuthentication.putBigUnicode(DataPartAuthentication.java:192)
        at com.sap.db.util.security.AuthenticationManager.addClientProofPart(AuthenticationManager.java:139)
        at com.sap.db.util.security.AbstractAuthenticationManager.connect(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:39)
        at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB.openSession(ConnectionSapDB.java:586)
        at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB.doConnect(ConnectionSapDB.java:436)
        at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB.<init>(ConnectionSapDB.java:195)
        at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDBFinalize.<init>(ConnectionSapDBFinalize.java:13)
        at com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:255)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
```

As you can see the exception is deep in SAP HANA JDBC Driver code, not my code. But I also don't understand what I could possibly be doing wrong in this situation ?

Any help and suggestions on how to debug this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only idea i have would be to search for the number 10 in your code...

Comment: The error is not coming from my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the stack trace references to the AuthenticationManager, are you positive your user name and password are correct? Also the method name putBigUnicode on the stacktrace makes me think there might be  some invalid character like a “ in there